# Spring MVC Input tag with Date throws error: HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and trying to build a form example in spring containing Date as a form element. But it is showing error "HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.", when click on the Submit button.

Note: I am using sql.Date for the date element.

Please help.

Code snippet is as follows

FormExample.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Form Example</h2>
    <form:form commandName="formExample" action="formExampleDetails" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>BirthDate:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <fmt:formatDate value="${birthDate.date}" pattern="dd-mmm-yyyy" var="birthDate"/>
                    <form:input path="birthDate" value="${birthDate}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller class i.e ApplicationControllerClass is as follows

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    @RequestMapping("/formExample")
    public String formExamplePage(ModelMap model){
        model.put("formExample", new FormExample());
        return "formExamplePage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/formExampleDetails",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String formExampleDetails(@ModelAttribute FormExample formExample,ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("BirthDate====>"+formExample.getBirthDate());
        return "index";
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
    }

}
```

Pojo class i.e FormExample.java is as follows

```
package com.spring.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

public class FormExample implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5527691555730303451L;

    private Date birthDate;

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `name` parameter into input like this <form:input name="birthDate" path="birthDate" value="${birthDate}"/>

Comment: @Oleg Kubatov- I tried with your solution. But It is still throwing the error. Note- I have removed the "initBinder" method from the controller class. I am using SQL Date as the type of birthday so it is throwing error. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may resolve this issue now. But for the other peoples sake I'll add the way I resolve this issue. Since I had to spent couple of hours to resolve this issue.

You can update your FormExample birthDate field as show in below.

```
          @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-mmm-yyyy")
          private Date birthDate;
```

This will correctly map the form object in to your pojo object and will not give the 400 BAD Request error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the `<form:form ...`tag.

**EDIT**
I could not recreate your error, so instead I tried to make your code work.

I don't have now the time to create a minimal setting, so I tried to insert the code in my own project which uses Spring 3.2. Everything works as it should if I make the following modifications:
first, removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`; second, modifying the controller code as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/formExampleDetails",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String formExampleDetails(@ModelAttribute FormExample formExample, BindingResult bindingResult){
    System.out.println("BirthDate====>"+formExample.getBirthDate());
    return "index";
}
```

(instead of the ModelMap argument, I pass the BindingResult argument - which should contain the possible errors, e.g. when you insert 11/11/2011 and not 11-11-2011). By the way, you better change the format dd-mmm-yyyy into dd-MM-yyyy.

I did not try to find out which of the modifications are really necessary and why; but this way it works. I will just remark that if you use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view the HTTP request, you will find out that `enctype="multipart/form-data"` changes the HTTP request format.

Comment: If one form contains both file type and Date type element, how to achieve this?

Comment: your form does not seem to contain any <input type="file"> elements. If you need both on the same page, it should be possible to have two forms on the same page - one for uploading a file, one for updating form values.

Comment: Ok. After removing the enctype="multipart/form-data", It is still throwing the same error.